Meander antenna in the corner of PCB
Can anybody think of a reason why I should not put an antenna in the corner of the PCB like this:

It is useful in my design because the board is quite big, and i cannot afford removing copper along the full edge of the board.

Probably not, though there may be some subtle affects because the board (FR4?) dielectric to air dielectric change is located at the bends rather than along the long edge.

You would be wasting the entire area on the edge and along the antenna. If you have other circuitry there, it is fine. You should also model the gap between your conductor plane and the antenna.

You callit a "meander antenna". That's a fun name but may HIDE the deadly seriousm=nss of its design requirements. You may know this aleady, and if so that's good:The design of these requires arcane knowledge and deep magic helps. There are a number of documents avaiable on designing them. If you don't have design guides you need them. Copying another board will be suboptimum and some commercial boards are already suboptimum or worse. I can dig up soe links if you cannot find any after a modest search.

Well, several things:

Standard disclaimers apply. We don't know what you're working with, and the whole scope of RF and EMC topics is vastly wider than the one narrow little thing you may be working with.  As such, I will assume some simple and common application (say, BLE), and go from there.  If you application is not simple, or common, expect to need further evaluation, tuning, research, etc.

I assume this design comes from a cookbook or application note that recommends specific dimensions for a band of interest.  Part of this design recommendation will be a specified keep-out region.  This will look like so:

It may be drawn as a clear board edge (dark green), but it does not need to take up "the full edge of the board", and different material is permissible in the hashed areas.  (You will almost certainly want ground plane in these areas, to shield any circuitry placed thereon.)

Putting it in the corner (as above, bottom) is fine as well.  This is effectively filling the space above the antenna with air, instead of blank FR-4 (and the ground plane edge behind it).

The closer any material is (or the absence thereof, as being in the corner is effectively cutting out both blank FR-4 and nearby ground plane around the element), the stronger an effect it has on the antenna tuning (frequency and impedance), and thus effect on the design.  If you were hoping to use a stock design with no subsequent tuning (VNA or at least SNA required, and preferably a coax test connector to use it with), the keepout dimensions will have to be on the larger side.


The nature of this type of antenna is "electrically short".  As a monopole element, electric field near the element is most important.  "Near" is relative to the dimension of the element itself.  So, d here might be a few times the zig-zag width.
It is also an electrically short dipole against the remainder of the PCB, i.e. the ground plane serves as counterpoise.  Thus, some common mode energy is carried on the bulk of the board (and into connectors and etc.), which can have consequences for sensitive applications, radiation pattern (if a precise/stable pattern is required), etc.
In short:
As an antenna, generally speaking: yes, that is fine.  Expect to need modest changes in the tuning/coupling component values.
As a given design, fixed dimensions, component values, testing not allowed (due to lack of equipment, time, budget, etc.): no, stick to the reference and obey the keep-out dimensions.

Thank you very much for your input. The reference is rather vague so i will definitely tune the antenna. The space is more constraining in my apllication so I will stick with the corner. Thank you once more and have a great day!
